# how to use object value as object name in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

how can i use the object value as object name

like this

```
$.each(columns, function(index, value) {
    var objectName = value.object; // need to pass this 
    to the next $.each
    //lets say i'm expecting objectName = x 
    $.each(values, function(i, v) {
        // console.log(v.x) ; // this works fine 
        console.log(v.objectName);
    });
});​
```

i have tried `toString()` it didn't work 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use square-bracket notation when using variables (identifiers) instead of actual object properties

```
console.log(v[objectName])
```

---

For futher reference on subject : http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html

> **String Variables as Identifiers**
>   The string used within the square brackets does not need to be a string literal. It can be any expression that results in a string. This is where the square bracket notation becomes most useful as the expression could be a reference to a string variable that holds the property name as its value, or a function call that returns a string, or an expression that concatenates two strings, or any combination of these [...]

Comment: Thanks it works , can you give us more explanation of your answer

Comment: can i do something like this $.each(values, function(index,value){ 
for(var i=0 ; i< columns.length ; i++){console.log(value[columns[i]])